# закладки со свёртываемым контентом

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap

В bootstrap есть отличные nav-tabs и nav-pills которые работают через
data-toggle="tab" создаётся пара секций:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active">
       <a data-toggle="tab" href="mySection1">Первая</a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a data-toggle="tab" href="mySection2">Вторая</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<section class="tab-content">
    <section id="mySection1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      ...
    </section>
    <section id="mySection2" class="tab-pane fade">
      ...
    </section>

     ... другие секции ...
</section>
```

И всё прекрасно, даже есть fade класс который добавляется в атрибут tab-pane чтобы переключение между вкладок было плавное, но когда много закладочек, и их высота сильно разнится, особенно превышая стандартную высоту вьюпорта, контент заметно подпрыгивает на переключениях из за резкозти смены размера контента, так-же в bootstrap есть такая вещь как accordion с классом collapse который делает плавно сворачивающиеся панельки между которыми можно переключаться, например вот такие:
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=accordion

Поскольку я не мастер вёрстки и js а только учусь, подскажите, как можно добавить свёртывание развёртывание контента, но в эти вот nav-tabs / nav-pills ?

Поскольку я провёл не один день в попытках найти что-то такое в гоголе и яндуксе, всё что я нашёл это https://css-tricks.com/organic-tabs/
они то как раз делают что надо, но хотелось бы не городить так много всего, а попробовать реализовать это дело максимально функционалом bootstrap и минимально jQuery.

Я также пробовал добавлять класс "collapse in" в активную и "collapse" в остальные вкладки и менять data-toggle на collapse как в аккордионах, но вкладки перестают реагировать на нажатия.

Подскажите люди добрые как-же победить этот вопрос?

Благодарю за внимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Задача**: Построить [закладки](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) `tabs` или [таблетки](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-pills) `pills` с эффектом сворачивания и разворачивания как у аккордеона. При этом обойтись штатными средствами бутстрапа, не дописывая свои скрипты и не добавляя чужие.

**Решил в три этапа**. Код в конце ответа показывает результаты всех трёх этапов.

1) Будем строить таблетки, потому что они ярче :) Начинаем строить не от таблеток к аккордеону, а от аккордеона к таблеткам. Берём из описания  бутстрапа [пример с аккордеоном](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion) и переставляем фрагменты кода, чтобы из трёх панелей получилось две. В верхнюю собираем все три заголовка, а в нижнюю - тексты к ним.

2) Скрещиваем заголовки

```
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
      Collapsible Group Item #2
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
```

с таблетками [из другого примера бутстрапа](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)

```
<li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
```

и получаем

```
<li role="presentation" id="headingTwo">
    <a class="collapsed" role="tab" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
      Collapsible Group Item #2
    </a>
</li>
```

3) Чтобы активная таблетка выделялась синим, нужно пристроить `class="active"` и `data-toggle="tab"`. Первый атрибут относился к пункту списка `<li>`, а второй - к ссылке внутри этого пункта. Но у ссылки уже есть `data-toggle="collapse"`. Поэтому оба оставшихся атрибута назначаем пункту списка.

**Результат**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
h3 { margin-top: 0.2em; }
.row { margin-top: 2em; }
</style>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1"><h3>1)</h3></div>
    <div class="col-xs-11">

      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne1">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne1">
                Item #1
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo1">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseTwo1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo1">
                Item #2
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree1">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseThree1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree1">
                Item #3
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div id="collapseOne1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne1">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo1">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...</p>
              <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree1">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...</p>
              <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...</p>
              <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div><!--row-->
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1"><h3>2)</h3></div>
    <div class="col-xs-11">

      <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" id="headingOne2">
            <a role="tab" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne2">
              Item #1
            </a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" id="headingTwo2">
            <a class="collapsed" role="tab" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo2">
              Item #2
            </a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" id="headingThree2">
            <a class="collapsed" role="tab" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree2">
              Item #3
            </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div id="collapseOne2" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne2">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo2">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...</p>
            <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree2">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...</p>
            <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...</p>
            <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
  </div><!--row-->
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1"><h3>3)</h3></div>
    <div class="col-xs-11">
  
        <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation" data-toggle="tab" class="active" id="headingOne3">
              <a role="tab" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#collapseOne3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne3">
                Item #1
              </a>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation" data-toggle="tab" id="headingTwo">
              <a class="collapsed" role="tab" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                Item #2
              </a>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation" data-toggle="tab" id="headingThree">
              <a class="collapsed" role="tab" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                Item #3
              </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion3" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div id="collapseOne3" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne3">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...</p>
              <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...</p>
              <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...</p>
              <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div><!--row-->
</div><!--container-->
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Можно посмотреть [живьём](http://glebkema.ru/tasks/so-ru-510709/) и [в песочнице](https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/xwrnashe/).

Comment: Утром протещу :))) вам надо постить решения на https://jsfiddle.net/ удобная песочница.

Comment: @VitalyProtasov Вот [живьём](http://glebkema.ru/tasks/so-ru-510709/). Вот [в песочнице](https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/xwrnashe/).

Comment: Круто, ещё бы сделать наползание контента не снизу а из под таблеток :)) инвертировать движение.