# Как переключать Bootstrap табы свайпом с эффектом slide

Tags: bootstrap, mobile, swipe, tab, эффекты

Здравствуйте, есть необходимость переключать Bootstrap табы свайпом, с эффектом slide. Сейчас использую код ниже, но переключение происходит с эффектом fade:

```
$(".tab-content").swiperight(function() {
    var $tab = $('#tablist .active').prev();
    if ($tab.length > 0)
        $tab.find('a').tab('show');
});
$(".tab-content").swipeleft(function() {
    var $tab = $('#tablist .active').next();
    if ($tab.length > 0)
        $tab.find('a').tab('show');
});
```

Comment: Сразу скажу, что код вам придется писать самому. В Bootstrap поддерживается только один тип анимации переключения табов - fade.

Comment: Может есть какой нибудь альтернативный вариант, допустим без Bootstrap?

Comment: Конечно есть - любой слайдер с поддержкой своих элементов управления. Например: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Вот так? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518013/208926